# Use RedirectToRouteResult with Area failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas, asp.net-mvc-filters

I'm using custom filter that check user access permission to specific Action and I have area called Admin. When filter redirect unauthorized user, its redirected inside area but not to the view in route directory.
For example, when I access http://localhost/admin/roles I expect that unauthorized user will be redicreted to http://localhost/authorized but not to http://localhost/admin/authorized as it's now.
Here is how I use filter:

```
   public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            DigitalHubOnlineStoreEntities db = new DigitalHubOnlineStoreEntities();
            RbacUser requestingUser = new RbacUser();
            var controllerid = RbacUser.GetControllerId(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName);
            var actionid = RbacUser.GetActionId(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName, controllerid);          
            if (!requestingUser.GetUserPermission(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, actionid, controllerid))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "action", "Index" }, { "controller", "Unauthorized" } });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to specify `Area` with en empty string:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary
                       {
                           { "action", "Index" },
                           { "controller", "Unauthorized" },
                           { "Area", String.Empty }
                       });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I suppose something like that.